# How to remove the author pages?

Tags: author

I submitted my site to Google and now the author page is showing up in the search results.

```
http://www.domain.com/author/myusername
```

How do I prevent my and others author names from showing up in search results?

It would be best to disable completely the path "/author/" all together because it's not a blog but a product site (it only has pages).

I did a search earlier and saw that there are plugins to do this but I'd rather not install a plugin (sometimes they are not updated) if there is another way but will if I have to.

I also searched through the source code of the pages and did not see any links to the author page.

Comment: why don;t you remove the author name links from posts?

Comment: I follow the link to the author page listed and it says no posts. So I don't know where the link is coming from.

Comment: http://blog.futtta.be/2015/03/03/quick-tip-disabling-wordpress-author-pages/

Comment: I know you're not looking for a plugin, but here is one for those who are looking: https://wordpress.org/plugins/disable-author-archives/

Comment: You can also change the `/author/myusername` to something else using this plugin - https://wordpress.org/plugins/edit-author-slug/

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The above answer is good, but if redirecting to home page, it should specify a 301 status and exit after.

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'my_custom_disable_author_page');

function my_custom_disable_author_page() {
    global $wp_query;

    if ( is_author() ) {
        // Redirect to homepage, set status to 301 permenant redirect. 
        // Function defaults to 302 temporary redirect. 
        wp_redirect(get_option('home'), 301); 
        exit; 
    }
}
```

wp_redirect() documentation https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_redirect/

Comment: I currently use Yoast SEO Plugin to remove author pages. Just change the option to not scan/index that taxonomy and you'll be good to go. No code required.

Comment: This is not a good solution for hiding author's pages. If you guess author's login, you will be redirected, but if you enter non-existing author's slug, you will get a 404 error. The right approach should redirect or gives 404 in all cases.

Comment: Why `global $wp_query;` ?

Answer (score 11):

You can also add the redirect to the author template directly. In your WordPress theme, edit the *author.php* file to redirect users to your homepage. If your theme doesn't have a template for author pages, create a file named *author.php*.

**author.php**: (Using php header function)

```php
<?php
//Redirect author pages to the homepage
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
header("Location: /");
die(); // avoid further PHP processing
//That's all folks
```

The `die()` part is to avoid that anyone using a client which does NOT follow the redirect header sees the content of the page since WP would continue building the original author page and send its response to the client requesting it.

---

**UPDATE**:
WordPress has a couple of built in functions to handle redirects: *wp_redirect()* and *wp_safe_redirect()*. *wp_redirect()* accepts a string as the redirect location and an integer as the redirect type (302 is the default). *wp_safe_redirect()* is the same as *wp_redirect()* except that it makes sure that the redirect location is found in a list of allowed hosts.

**author.php**: (Using WordPress wp_safe_redirect function)

```php
<?php
//Redirect author pages to the homepage with WordPress redirect function
wp_safe_redirect( get_home_url(), 301 );
exit;
//That's all folks
```

More information

- WordPress template hierarchy:
  https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/
- PHP header function: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php
- WordPress wp_safe_redirect function: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_safe_redirect

Answer (score 6):

You can disable the access to author pages by adding this  snippet to functions.php:

```
// Disable access to author page
add_action('template_redirect', 'my_custom_disable_author_page');

function my_custom_disable_author_page() {
    global $wp_query;

    if ( is_author() ) {
        $wp_query->set_404();
        status_header(404);
        // Redirect to homepage
        // wp_redirect(get_option('home'));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can disable the access to author pages if you add the following code in functions.php: file

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'my_custom_disable_author_page');

    function my_custom_disable_author_page() {
        global $wp_query;
        if ( is_author() ) {
            $wp_query->set_404();
            status_header(404);
        }
    }
```